# How do you set -DargLine system property inside MAVEN_OPTS environment variable?

Tags: shell, maven, command-line, environment-variables, system-properties

I'm using maven and have a list of system properties `-DA=alpha`, `-DB=beta` `-DS=random_stuff` that I want to pass down to unit tests when maven runs, and which cannot go into the `pom` files.

[Surefire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) and [Failsafe](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) plugins both basically say you can pass values down to tests by passing them via the `-DargLine` system property.

Usually it's defined in the `pom.xml`, e.g.

```
<argLine>-DA=alpha -DB=beta -DS=random_stuff</argLine>
```

But I have also seen examples where `-DargLine=...` was passed in from the command line.

I believe that I need to put quotes around the system properties I want to pass in via `argLine`, as they are space separated:

```
-DargLine="-DA=alpha -DB=beta -DS=random_stuff"
```

And now I want to pass them in via the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable (which also "carries" other system properties, not just `argLine`). What I have so far is:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Dxyz=abc ... -DargLine=\"-DA=alpha -DB=beta -DS=random_stuff\""
```

In other words, I escaped `argLine`'s quotes. Unfortunately, the end quote is now treated as part of `-DS`'s value, i.e. `S` now gets replaced by `random_stuff"` - not what I want.

How can I do what I want to do, i.e. make sure `A`, `B`, and `S` are passed in as part of `argLine`, and pass `argLine` through as part of `MAVEN_OPTS`?

P.S.: I also tired inner single quotes (equally unusable result: `some_stuff'`) and [unescaped inner double quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345537/95276) (`MAVEN_OPTS=" ... -DargLine="-DA=alpha ...""`, resulting in errors when trying to source `.bash_profile`), both unsuccessfully...

Comment: Why can they not go into the pom files?

Comment: Because they contain data we don't want anywhere near our VCS system.